# Is Data.Map the best data type for a binary search tree?

Tags: performance, haskell, binary-search-tree

I'm writing some performance-sensitive code which requires a lookup in a binary search tree. The tree itself will be generated once at the beginning of each run, and then never modified. Lookups will be performed quite often, easily in the millions, so I'm only concerned with lookup performance.

The keys of the tree are `Char`s and can cheaply be converted to `Int`, so I assumed that `Data.Map` and cousins would be the best choice: I'm using a strict `IntMap` here. However, I'm getting performance significantly below what I would expect from a binary search tree. I demonstrate here with a rather contrived example.

```
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM


divideByTen :: Int -> Int
divideByTen n = maybe 0 snd $ IM.lookupLE n divideByTenMap

divideByTenMap :: IM.IntMap Int
divideByTenMap = IM.fromList $ zip [0,10..1000] [0..]
```

My data will not be uniformly distributed, so performance of certain subsets will be more important than overall. Hence it makes sense to introduce some shortcuts for these commonly used inputs.

```
divideByTenFaster :: Int -> Int
divideByTenFaster n
  | n < 10  = 0
  | n < 20  = 1
  | n < 30  = 2
  | n < 40  = 3
  | n < 50  = 4
  | n < 60  = 5
  | n < 70  = 6
  | n < 80  = 7
  | n < 90  = 8
  | n < 100 = 9
  | otherwise = divideByTen n
```

There are 100 elements of this `IntMap`, so a binary search should take at most 7 comparisons. Hence I would expect `divideByTenFaster` to be faster than `divideByTen` for `n < 70`, and slower afterwards. What I see instead is that `divideByTenFaster` is twice as fast as the `IntMap` lookup, even for `n < 100`. Running the following benchmarking code:

```
import Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = do
    defaultMainWith defaultConfig $
      [ bench "divideByTen"       $ nf divideByTen 99
      , bench "divideByTenFaster" $ nf divideByTenFaster 99
      ]
```

we get

```
benchmarking divideByTen
time                 18.50 ns   (18.47 ns .. 18.54 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 18.49 ns   (18.47 ns .. 18.51 ns)
std dev              79.42 ps   (61.51 ps .. 110.3 ps)

benchmarking divideByTenFaster
time                 7.164 ns   (7.154 ns .. 7.176 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 7.161 ns   (7.145 ns .. 7.176 ns)
std dev              49.60 ps   (36.84 ps .. 68.32 ps)
```

In my real problem I'm seeing even more significant differences: the `IntMap` lookup is up to an order of magnitude slower. I've found myself writing long and difficult-to-maintain shortcuts, essentially manually building an unbalanced binary search tree, which significantly improves performance in common cases, and slows down the general case slightly.

I could move to an array-based solution, but I had thought this was the ideal use case for `Map`. Are there some optimisations I'm missing, or is another data type a better choice?

For full context the problem I'm dealing with is looking up Unicode character width, as determined by the Unicode specification. The lookup tree has around 700 to 1100 elements, depending on context. Performance of the ASCII subset is very important, and beyond that widely-used scripts should be quite fast (Latin, Han ideographs, Arabic, Devanagari, etc.), while performance for lesser-used scripts can be sacrificed a bit.

Edit:

Given the many suggestions in the comments, I've benchmarked a few different approaches to this problem. For pure lookup performance nothing beats a giant array, though that requires a non-trivial memory and construction cost, but other approaches all perform similarly, with the exception of directly implementing Data.Map.Strict's structure here (thanks to @dfeuer's comment below).

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import qualified Data.Map.Internal as MInt
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU

bstSize :: Int
bstSize = 800

domainSize :: Int
domainSize = 1100000

divideByTenShortcut :: Int -> Int
divideByTenShortcut n
  | n < 10 = 0
  | n < 20 = 1
  | n < 30 = 2
  | n < 40 = 3
  | n < 50 = 4
  | n < 60 = 5
  | n < 70 = 6
  | n < 80 = 7
  | n < 90 = 8
  | n < 100 = 9
  | otherwise = divideByTenIntMapLookup n

divideByTenIntMapLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenIntMapLookup n = maybe 0 snd $ IM.lookupLE n divideByTenIntMap

divideByTenIntMap :: IM.IntMap Int
divideByTenIntMap = IM.fromList $ zip [0,10..bstSize*10] [0..]

divideByTenMapLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenMapLookup n = maybe 0 snd $ M.lookupLE n divideByTenMap

divideByTenMap :: M.Map Int Int
divideByTenMap = M.fromList $ zip [0,10..bstSize*10] [0..]

arrayBinarySearch :: G.Vector v Int => v Int -> Int -> Int
arrayBinarySearch vs search = loop 0 (G.length vs)
  where
    loop !low !high
       | high <= low = low
       | otherwise = case compare midval search of
            LT -> loop midpoint high
            GT -> loop low (midpoint - 1)
            EQ -> midpoint
      where
        midpoint = (low + high + 1) `quot` 2
        midval = G.unsafeIndex vs midpoint

divideByTenArrayLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenArrayLookup n = let i = arrayBinarySearch divideByTenArray n in V.unsafeIndex divideByTenArraySols i

divideByTenArray :: V.Vector Int
divideByTenArray = V.fromList [0,10..bstSize*10]

divideByTenArraySols :: V.Vector Int
divideByTenArraySols = V.fromList [0..bstSize]

divideByTenArrayUnboxedLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenArrayUnboxedLookup n = let i = arrayBinarySearch divideByTenArrayUnboxed n in VU.unsafeIndex divideByTenArrayUnboxedSols i

divideByTenArrayUnboxed :: VU.Vector Int
divideByTenArrayUnboxed = VU.fromList [0,10..bstSize*10]

divideByTenArrayUnboxedSols :: VU.Vector Int
divideByTenArrayUnboxedSols = VU.fromList [0..bstSize]

divideByTenFullArrayLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenFullArrayLookup = V.unsafeIndex divideByTenFullArray

divideByTenFullArray :: V.Vector Int
divideByTenFullArray = V.fromList $ map (`quot` 10) [0..domainSize]

divideByTenFullArrayUnboxedLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenFullArrayUnboxedLookup = VU.unsafeIndex divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed

divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed :: VU.Vector Int
divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed = VU.fromList $ map (`quot` 10) [0..domainSize]

divideByTenCharMapLookup :: Int -> Int
divideByTenCharMapLookup n = lookupLE n divideByTenCharMap

divideByTenCharMap :: CharMap
divideByTenCharMap = fromList $ zip [0,10..bstSize*10] [0..]

data CharMap = Bin {-# UNPACK #-} !Size !Int !Int !CharMap !CharMap
             | Tip
type Size     = Int

lookupLE :: Int -> CharMap -> Int
lookupLE = goNothing
  where
    goNothing !_ Tip = 0
    goNothing k (Bin _ kx x l r) = case compare k kx of LT -> goNothing k l
                                                        EQ -> x
                                                        GT -> goJust k kx x r

    goJust !_ !_ x' Tip = x'
    goJust k kx' x' (Bin _ kx x l r) = case compare k kx of LT -> goJust k kx' x' l
                                                            EQ -> x
                                                            GT -> goJust k kx x r
{-# INLINABLE lookupLE #-}

fromList :: [(Int, Int)] -> CharMap
fromList = repack . M.fromList
  where
    repack MInt.Tip = Tip
    repack (MInt.Bin s k v l r) = Bin s k v (repack l) (repack r)



import Control.Exception (evaluate)
import Criterion.Main

main :: IO ()
main = do
    evaluate divideByTenIntMap
    evaluate divideByTenMap
    evaluate divideByTenCharMap
    evaluate divideByTenArray
    evaluate divideByTenArrayUnboxed
    evaluate divideByTenFullArray
    evaluate divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed

    defaultMainWith defaultConfig
      [ bench "divideByTenIntMap"           $ nf divideByTenIntMapLookup 99
      , bench "divideByTenShortcut"         $ nf divideByTenShortcut 99
      , bench "divideByTenMap"              $ nf divideByTenMapLookup 99
      , bench "divideByTenCharMap"          $ nf divideByTenCharMapLookup 99

      , bench "divideByTenArray"            $ nf divideByTenArrayLookup 99
      , bench "divideByTenArrayUnboxed"     $ nf divideByTenArrayUnboxedLookup 99
      , bench "divideByTenFullArray"        $ nf divideByTenFullArrayLookup 99
      , bench "divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed" $ nf divideByTenFullArrayUnboxedLookup 99
      ]
```

```
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.7 -O1

benchmarking divideByTenIntMap
time                 21.31 ns   (21.26 ns .. 21.36 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 21.31 ns   (21.27 ns .. 21.36 ns)
std dev              137.3 ps   (104.7 ps .. 190.5 ps)

benchmarking divideByTenShortcut
time                 6.881 ns   (6.868 ns .. 6.893 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.896 ns   (6.873 ns .. 6.947 ns)
std dev              112.5 ps   (40.52 ps .. 184.2 ps)
variance introduced by outliers: 23% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking divideByTenMap
time                 23.31 ns   (22.94 ns .. 23.68 ns)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 23.02 ns   (22.91 ns .. 23.26 ns)
std dev              500.1 ps   (245.4 ps .. 865.6 ps)
variance introduced by outliers: 33% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking divideByTenCharMap
time                 15.89 ns   (15.88 ns .. 15.92 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 15.90 ns   (15.88 ns .. 15.92 ns)
std dev              68.89 ps   (44.90 ps .. 113.1 ps)

benchmarking divideByTenArray
time                 27.07 ns   (27.01 ns .. 27.13 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 27.03 ns   (26.92 ns .. 27.13 ns)
std dev              334.5 ps   (248.0 ps .. 474.7 ps)
variance introduced by outliers: 14% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking divideByTenArrayUnboxed
time                 22.89 ns   (22.82 ns .. 22.99 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 22.94 ns   (22.84 ns .. 23.10 ns)
std dev              418.6 ps   (301.6 ps .. 555.1 ps)
variance introduced by outliers: 26% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking divideByTenFullArray
time                 6.639 ns   (6.626 ns .. 6.651 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.635 ns   (6.626 ns .. 6.644 ns)
std dev              28.87 ps   (24.14 ps .. 34.83 ps)

benchmarking divideByTenFullArrayUnboxed
time                 6.029 ns   (6.017 ns .. 6.041 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.021 ns   (6.013 ns .. 6.029 ns)
std dev              26.09 ps   (21.68 ps .. 31.51 ps)

Benchmark doclayout-bench: FINISH
```

So the problem doesn't seem to be with `IntMap` *per se*. Checking the output of `-ddump-simpl` also shows that values seem to be being unboxed appropriately.

Comment: There's a lot that could be going on here. For example, the divideByTenFaster will have better characteristics due to less data demand on branch prediction and cache, right?  Either way, I suggest you share the full benchmark code so others won't have to reproduce and are more inclined to play around.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I agree that there's likely some overhead, but this goes partly towards the thrust of my question. If the overhead of an IntMap is significant enough to render it an order of magnitude less efficient (2x in this case), then it is not a good data type to use for a binary search, and my interpretation of its strengths is incorrect.

I have added the benchmarking code.

Comment: On my machine, adding `evaluate (divideByTen 800)` at the start of `main` brings the two closer together (not all the way, just a bit).

Comment: "A binary search tree" cannot be a requirement, unless you are doing a course on binary search trees. "A fast map" could be a requirement. A map implemented with a sorted array will always give you better search performance than one implemented with a BST. It will give you worse update performance, but since you are not updating, it's a no-brainer.

Comment: A trivial hash map (with hash = id) would have better performance still. Given that Unicode is not exceedingly large, just 2^21 code points, it is not unreasonable to keep a 2^21 long array, even though only a few per cent of it will be used.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  This is absolutely correct, however it's not obvious what the magnitude of the difference would be. A lot can be hidden in O(log n), but I would be surprised at a 10x difference.

Comment: Well you can always do some experiments and see for yourself. I would try an array of unboxed elements where each element is an unboxed key plus a possibly boxed value. Dereferencing is more expensive than comparison. I would expect at least 2x-3x difference.

Comment: Factors of 2× or even 20× are absolutely within what you should expect as overhead between different data structures for operations with the same complexity.

Comment: `IntMap` is *not* a binary search tree; it's a PATRICIA tree (a form of trie). It *typically* performs better than `Map` for `Int`-like things, but that's not entirely guaranteed. If you want to experiment with a binary search tree, you could copy/paste the code you need from `Data.Map.Strict` and `Data.Map.Internal`, but replace the `k` field with a `Char` field and the `v` field with a strict `Int` field. These will be unboxed automatically, removing indirections and making the structure more compact.

Comment: I just read that you're exclusively interested in lookup performance. For that, a big array will probably be good. Another option would be an array-mapped trie. I know Wren Romano did some work on those, but I don't know if she ever made the code public. You could hack `Data.HashMap` into a non-hashed version with some work, but I imagine getting really good performance will be a fair bit of work.

Comment: @dfeuer Your suggestion to copy the Data.Map structure directly to get rid of indirections results in some notable preformance improvements, and corrects a misunderstanding I had about IntMaps. I think it would be worthwhile promoting it to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at this package: [hashtables](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables). It implements multiple mutable hash tables and, from the description, it seems like you could use some `cabal` flags to try to speed things up, e.g., `sse42` to speed up cache-line searches for cuckoo hashing.